# If __name__ == "__main__":

Tags: python, module, selenium-chromedriver

In .py file I have some functions which are being called in if **name** == "**main**": other than this, chrome driver is also initialized there.
def func1:
def func2:

```
if __name__=="__main__":

    chromedriver

    value = func1()
    func2()
```

Now, I want to call this whole file/module in another file. what should I have to do? What is the easiest way for this?

Comment: Did my answer solve your prolblem? If that is the case please accept it, else describe  your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Move everything underneath the `if __name__=="__main__":` into a `main()` method and call that from `if __name__=="__main__":`

```py
def main():
    driver = create_chrome_driver()
    value = func1()
    func2()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

And call it as well as from your other file:

```py
import mymodule
mymodule.main()
```

Comment: I took the liberty of elaborating.